# log4j2 rollover strategy not working as expected

Tags: log4j2, weblogic12c

I have a Log4j2.xml defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">E:/MLM/MLMDomain/servers/${sys:weblogic.Name}/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/MLMServices.log" filePattern="${log-path}/MLMServices-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%c{1}] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
           <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
       </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

From what I understand, my log file should roll over to new one when it reaches 1MB. The number of files to roll over should be 30. However, if you look at my logs below, there are over 40 of them, and all the latest ones are all close to 30MB. The current log file MLMServices.log has entries from 13 Apr 2016 till now. In fact, the last few log files, MLMServices-2016-05-24-4.log, MLMServices-2016-05-24-3.log, etc, have entries from 13 Apr 2016. When a new log file is created, it duplicates the entries from the previous one, and then append more entries. So progressively each new log file will be slightly bigger than the previous one.

```
04/28/2016  04:26 PM         1,050,290 MLMServices-2016-04-28-1.log
04/28/2016  06:02 PM         1,188,994 MLMServices-2016-04-28-2.log
04/29/2016  12:11 PM         1,315,487 MLMServices-2016-04-29-1.log
04/29/2016  12:21 PM         1,364,634 MLMServices-2016-04-29-2.log
04/29/2016  12:30 PM         1,413,781 MLMServices-2016-04-29-3.log
04/29/2016  05:02 PM         1,472,373 MLMServices-2016-04-29-4.log
05/03/2016  04:16 PM         2,521,056 MLMServices-2016-05-03-1.log
05/04/2016  04:35 PM         3,379,593 MLMServices-2016-05-04-1.log
05/05/2016  01:47 PM         3,715,698 MLMServices-2016-05-05-1.log
05/05/2016  02:47 PM         3,858,833 MLMServices-2016-05-05-2.log
05/06/2016  02:13 PM         4,908,446 MLMServices-2016-05-06-1.log
05/06/2016  02:46 PM         4,927,119 MLMServices-2016-05-06-2.log
05/06/2016  03:04 PM         5,068,610 MLMServices-2016-05-06-3.log
05/06/2016  05:07 PM         5,267,743 MLMServices-2016-05-06-4.log
05/10/2016  03:16 PM         8,598,426 MLMServices-2016-05-10-1.log
05/10/2016  03:16 PM        11,280,054 MLMServices-2016-05-10-2.log
05/10/2016  03:16 PM        12,328,667 MLMServices-2016-05-10-3.log
05/10/2016  03:16 PM        13,377,298 MLMServices-2016-05-10-4.log
05/10/2016  03:16 PM        14,425,881 MLMServices-2016-05-10-5.log
05/10/2016  03:16 PM        15,474,464 MLMServices-2016-05-10-6.log
05/10/2016  03:16 PM        16,523,059 MLMServices-2016-05-10-7.log
05/10/2016  03:16 PM        17,571,640 MLMServices-2016-05-10-8.log
05/10/2016  03:53 PM        18,620,566 MLMServices-2016-05-10-9.log
05/11/2016  02:37 PM        19,002,926 MLMServices-2016-05-11-1.log
05/11/2016  02:44 PM        19,088,104 MLMServices-2016-05-11-2.log
05/11/2016  03:50 PM        19,375,771 MLMServices-2016-05-11-3.log
05/14/2016  01:51 PM        20,424,415 MLMServices-2016-05-14-1.log
05/16/2016  12:52 PM        21,473,018 MLMServices-2016-05-16-1.log
05/17/2016  07:01 PM        22,521,671 MLMServices-2016-05-17-1.log
05/18/2016  09:57 AM        23,570,365 MLMServices-2016-05-18-1.log
05/18/2016  02:03 PM        24,619,048 MLMServices-2016-05-18-2.log
05/18/2016  08:05 PM        25,667,655 MLMServices-2016-05-18-3.log
05/19/2016  09:18 AM        25,786,502 MLMServices-2016-05-19-1.log
05/19/2016  02:00 PM        26,259,036 MLMServices-2016-05-19-2.log
05/19/2016  05:52 PM        26,593,795 MLMServices-2016-05-19-3.log
05/19/2016  06:26 PM        26,671,744 MLMServices-2016-05-19-4.log
05/20/2016  03:30 PM        27,191,829 MLMServices-2016-05-20-1.log
05/20/2016  05:27 PM        28,240,467 MLMServices-2016-05-20-2.log
05/23/2016  06:10 PM        29,204,271 MLMServices-2016-05-23-1.log
05/24/2016  09:55 AM        29,338,523 MLMServices-2016-05-24-1.log
05/24/2016  10:31 AM        29,441,164 MLMServices-2016-05-24-2.log
05/24/2016  12:04 PM        29,556,676 MLMServices-2016-05-24-3.log
05/24/2016  12:05 PM        29,577,736 MLMServices-2016-05-24-4.log
05/20/2016  05:27 PM        29,734,763 MLMServices.log
```

This is not the behavior that I want. I just want each log file to be limited to 1MB, and I want to keep a maximum of 30 log files. Where in the configuration did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance

**Edited: I have actually specified log4j2 in weblogic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
       http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:context-root>XXXXXX</wls:context-root>
    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>jax-rs</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>2.0</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>log4j</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if something besides your application is accessing MLMServices.log. On Windows, file renames and deletes will fail if an exclusive lock cannot be obtained.

Comment: I don't think something else is accessing the log file. To test again, I changed log4j2.xml by renaming "MLMServices.log" to "TestServices.log". I also changed SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size value to "100KB", and DefaultRolloverStrategy max value to "5". Then I restarted my application. When TestServices.log reached 100KB, it was  duplicated into TestServices-2016-05-26-1.log. But the content of "TestServices.log" was not truncated, and instead further log entries are appended into it. So "TestServices.log" will forever keep growing without truncation.

Comment: My application is run under a Weblogic server. I think WebLogic is locking the log file, although I am not sure how WebLogic could know the existence of the log file.

Comment: See my edit above. I have specified log4j in weblogic.xml.